# Object inheritance involving enumerated types

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Delphi 2007, moving to Delphi XE over the next year.

Our product makes extensive use of a third-party component. We don't use the component directly, but instead use a custom descendant of it, to which we've added quite a lot of extra behavior (the custom descendant component was developed several years ago by developers who have since have retired).

In the source unit of the third-party Parent class, some enumerated types are declared, which control various operations of the component:

```
TSpecialKind = (skAlpha, skBeta, skGamma);
TSpecialKinds = set of TSpecialKind;
```

In our descendant class, we want to add new behavior, which would require expanding the selection of enumerated types. Essentially, we want this:

```
TSpecialKind = (skAlpha, skBeta, skGamma, skDelta, skEpsilon);
TSpecialKinds = set of TSpecialKind;
```

Obviously, we want to avoid editing the third-party code. Is it valid to simply redeclare the enumerated type, repeating the original values and adding our new ones, *in our own descendent unit*? Will it have any effect on existing code?

Edit:
Example scenario to (hopefully) clarify. Say you've got a (parent) component for ordering vehicle parts. The parent unit has an enumerated type Tvkind for vehicle kind, with values vkCar and vkCycle defined. These values are used, among other things, to indicate how many wheels the vehicle has, 4 or 2.

Now, in your descendent component, you want to be able to handle 3-wheeled vehicles as well. Extending the Tvkind enumerated type to include a new value vkTrike seems like the obvious approach. But what if you don't have access to or don't want to modify the parent component code?

Comment: What are you going to do with these new types. You can't use them in the original component.

Comment: @David The new types would only be used in our descended component. There are a lot of routines (both in the parent and the child classes) which expect values of type TSpecialKind. In our component, we want to add functionality that suggests extending the values of TSpecialKind. I'll add an example scenario to the post.

Comment: So suppose you add `vkTrike`. What value do you pass to the original component? Your only options are `vkCar` and `vkCycle`. I don't think your proposed design will work at all.

Comment: We're never actually using the original component at all. We only make use of our own descendent. My gut feeling up front was that this wouldn't work, and your and Cosmin's answers support this. Fortunately, I _do_ have the parent source, so I may settle for the non-optimal approach of simply adding it there. I'll just have to remember to re-modify every time we get an updated component.

Comment: You most definitely are using the original component. You created a derived class. For sure the original component's code will be running.

Comment: Ah, yes, fair enough. We don't use it directly, but all of it is in our descendent.

Comment: If you go the route of modifying the vendor's component, I'd *highly* recommend putting its source into a repository that will let you easily pull in updates from the vendor.  I've gone down this path before and it got far, far easier to update once I started using Mercurial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can reasonably expect to make the change that you want without modifying the original component.

Let's take your vehicle kind example and delve a bit deeper. I expect that the original component will have code like this:

```
case Kind of
vkCar:
  CarMethod;
vkCycle:
  CycleMethod;
end;
```

Now, suppose you introduce an enumerated type with an extra enumeration

```
TExtendedVehicleKind = (vkCar, vkCycle, vkTrike);
```

If the case statement above runs, with `ExtendedKind` equal to `vkTrike`, no method will be called.

Now, perhaps the behaviour that you want from the original control can be achieved by setting `Kind` to `vkCar` or `vkCycle` when `ExtendedKind` is `vkTrike`. But that seems unlikely to me. Only you can know for sure, because only you have the code, and know what your actual problem is.

Comment: "No method would be called", as in your example, might not be that bad. What if an `TCarOperator` is created for `vkCar`, an `TCycleOperator` created for `vkCycle` and then the method `TVehicleOperator.StartEngine` is called? It would AV for `vkTrike` because no `TVehicleOperator` is created and the code has no reason to check if it created it or not.

Comment: @CosminPrund Avoiding an AV by doing nothing rather than doing something that is needed hardly solves the problem. I'd always opt for the AV over the silent failure.

Comment: I know. I'm hoping the OP would better understand the situation by presenting a more immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is essentially the answer I expected - 'Extending' an enum type in a descendant unit can't or shouldn't be done. We've decided to take an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance for enumeration types doesn't work the same way it works for Classes because code makes assumptions about enumerations that it would never make about a class. For example, given your original enumeration (the `TSpecialKind`), the third party component likely includes code like this:

```
var Something: TSpecialKind;
[...]
case Something of
  skAlpha: ;
  skBeta: ;
  skGamma: ;
end;
```

Even if you could cast something that's not part of that enumeration to the `TSpecialKind` type, the result of that code above would be *undefined* (and definitively not good!)

Enumerations might be used in one other way, and if the third party component only uses it that way, then you might be able to do some "wizardry", but I don't recommend it. If the original `TSpecialKind` is only used through it's `TSpecialKinds` set type, and then it's only used like this:

```
if skBeta in VarOfTypeSpecialKinds then
begin
  ...
end;
```

(continued) then you could introduce a new type that enumerates all of the original values, in the same order, with the same value. If after you do that `SizeOf(TSpecialKind)` equals `SizeOf(TNewType)` then you can hard-cast the new *set* value to the old value and the old code would work the same. But frankly this is hacky, to many conditions for it to work properly, too fragile. The better solution would be to use a new enumeration type that's only used in your descendant component:

```
type TExtraSpecialKind = (skDelta, skEpsilon);
     TExtraSpecialKinds = set of TExtraSpecialKind;
```

You'll probably have this set published in a different property; The solution is clean, will mix well with the descendant code and can be used cleanly too. Example:

```
if (skAlpha in SpecialKind) or (skDelta in ExtraSpecialKind) then
begin
  // Do extra-sepcial mixed stuff here.
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Been in the "need to extended the enumerated type of a property".

Quick First Suggestion. Add your enumeration, as a new property wrapper to the existing property:

---

Potential Parent class code:

---

```
unit AcmeMachines;

interface

type
   FoodCanEnum =
   (
     None,
     Fish,
     Bird,
     Beef
   );

   AcmeCanAutoOpenMachineClass= class (object)
   protected
   { protected declarations }

      F_FoodCanEnum: FoodCanEnum;

      function getFoodEnumProperty: FoodCanEnum;
      procedure setFoodEnumProperty(const AValue: FoodCanEnum);
   public
   { public declarations }

      property FoodEnumProperty
        read getFoodEnumProperty write setFoodEnumProperty;
   end;

implementation

   function AcmeCanAutoOpenMachineClass.getMyFoodEnumProperty: FoodCanEnum;
   begin        
     Result := F_FoodCanEnum;
   end;

   procedure AcmeCanAutoOpenMachineClass.setMyFoodEnumProperty
     (const AValue: CatFoodCanEnum);
   begin    
     FoodEnumProperty:= AValue;

     // do some specific business logic
   end;

end;
```

---

Descendant Class code:

---

```
unit UmbrellaMachines;

interface
uses AcmeMachines;

type
   CatFoodCanEnum =
   (
     None, <--- matches "AcmeMachines.None"
     Fish, <--- matches "AcmeMachines.Fish"
     Bird, <--- matches "AcmeMachines.Bird"
     Beef, <--- matches "AcmeMachines.Beef"
     Tuna,
     Chicken
   );

   UmbrellaCanAutoOpenMachineClass = class (AcmeCanAutoOpenMachineClass)
   protected
   { protected declarations }

      F_CatFoodCanEnum: CatFoodCanEnum;

      function getMyFoodEnumProperty: CatFoodCanEnum;
      procedure setMyFoodEnumProperty(const AValue: CatFoodCanEnum);
   public
   { public declarations }

      // new property, "wraps" existing property
      property MyFoodEnumProperty
        read getMyFoodEnumProperty write setMyFoodEnumProperty;
   end;

implementation

   function UmbrellaCanAutoOpenMachineClass.getMyFoodEnumProperty: CatFoodCanEnum;
   begin
     // wrap existing "FoodEnumProperty" property, using an existing value as dummy

     Result := F_CatFoodCanEnum;
   end;

   procedure UmbrellaCanAutoOpenMachineClass.setMyFoodEnumProperty
     (const AValue: CatFoodCanEnum);
   begin
     // wrap existing property, using an existing value as dummy
     // may be another value if necessary
     AcmeCanAutoOpenMachineClass.ExistingFoodEnumProperty := AcmeMachines.None;

     F_CatFoodCanEnum := AValue;
     // add extended business logic for this class instances
   end;

end;
```

- Extra.

If possible, always add a "null" or "dummy" value to your own enumerations, usually, the first value:

```
 type
   CatFoodCanEnum =
   (
     None, // <--- these one
     Tuna,
     Chicken,
     Beef
   );
```

Cheers.

Comment: What you wrote there doesn't compile, because it's not Delphi pascal. Delphi properties need `read` and `write` accessors, not `set` and `get`; Properties need to specify their type, unless they are inherited from the parent (and in that case you can't change the type). There are other errors as well. Your answer is 99% code but it can't stand on it's own since it doesn't even compile. I'll revert my downvote when you make the code compile, and please include the parent class declaration as well as a demonstration of when this might be useful, because I don't see it.

Comment: Thnks. I fix. I dont have Delphi in this machine. Working with C# and got mix up.

Comment: Maybe you should delete the answer and post it again after you get it through a Delphi compiler, and please add that parent class + a couple of method calls. I've already (tried) doing that for you so I know you're going to face some difficult problems; The enumerations can't have the same name as those in the parent, even the enumeration elements can't have the same names, calling a method introduced in the parent that takes an enumeration value would be quite difficult. I don't downvote easily, especially when I have a competing answer!

Comment: ughh, your answer seems more that trolling that adding help. Yes, the code its incomplete, and many answers are, and still marked as correct. The enumeration properties have different name, and two enumeration types can have values with the same id, the programmer just have to prefixed ...

Comment: Trolling... I told you **the code doesn't compile**, and it still doesn't after 2 edits. I suggested you delete the answer until you can get it fixed, you'd be able to undelete it after you get it through a compiler. You didn't even fix everything I told you about in my *first* comment. Well it's your answer, I'm not going to volunteer any more help or comments especially since you think I'm trolling.

Comment: umlcat: Constructive criticism isn't "trolling", and if you think it is you should either avoid posting here or make sure that anything you post is 100% compilable and tested.